# how to add the Log call and New task button?

Tags: opportunity, tasks

how to add the Log call and New task button ? like below screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Quick Actions.

You configure Quick Actions on the underlying Page Layout for this specific sObject and Record Type. Position Quick Actions in the Lightning and Mobile Quick Actions section (at the top of the page layout editor) to have them appear in the Chatter publisher.

Optionally, create new object-specific Quick Actions in Object Manager for this sObject to make them available in the Quick Actions palette. This step is not required for New Task and Log Call, which are built-in. Note however that sObjects which don't allow Activities won't have these Quick Actions available with the same functionality.